# Free Tool for Validating 2 Databases

Tags: mysql, database, linux, validation, testing

I want a free tool for verification all table data between 2 mysql databases ?

is there any free tool available on Linux

Answer (score 1):

Try [mysqldiff](http://www.mysqldiff.org/) which uses PHP to compare two MySQL databases. It's freeware too.

My mistake; that tool only does database structure differences and not data differences.

Answer (score 1):

In [Toad for MySQL](http://www.quest.com/mysql/) : you can compare 2 database and it is free.

[DataBase Workbench](http://www.upscene.com) made this too but it is not free

Available on Linux with Wine.